# what is a proper security.yml file for getting users from a database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have some troubles with my security.yml file:

```
# you can read more about security in the related section of the documentation
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password
    encoders:
        #Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Login\Loginbundle\Entity\User: sha512

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        users:
            entity: { class: LoginLoginBundle:User, property: username }
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    # the main part of the security, where you can set up firewalls
    # for specific sections of your app
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/

            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                provider: users
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I have a website that has a login form. The users are located in a database.
I can login with username: user and password: userpass but how can I get it to work with the users from the database?

I have read about UserInterfaces and fooled around with it, without succes.

Maybe the user entity is helpfull, here it is:

```
<?php

namespace Login\LoginBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * User
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $money;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $userid;

    /**
     * @var \Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Team
     */
    private $teamTeamid;

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }



    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set money
     *
     * @param integer $money
     * @return User
     */
    public function setMoney($money)
    {
        $this->money = $money;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get money
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getMoney()
    {
        return $this->money;
    }

    /**
     * Get userid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUserid()
    {
        return $this->userid;
    }

    /**
     * Set teamTeamid
     *
     * @param \Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Team $teamTeamid
     * @return User
     */
    public function setTeamTeamid(\Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Team $teamTeamid = null)
    {
        $this->teamTeamid = $teamTeamid;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get teamTeamid
     *
     * @return \Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Team 
     */
    public function getTeamTeamid()
    {
        return $this->teamTeamid;
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to edit my security.yml file and acces the database users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to log in with users from a database?

If you try to login with name 'user' and pass 'userpass', this should work.

If you want to work with users from the database, you should edit your security.yml file like this

```
providers:
        user:
            entity:
                class: Login\LoginBundle\Entity\User
                property: username
```

Comment: I have edited my code and I had some problems with the encoding, but everything is working now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understanding the question.  But the easiest way to deal with users in symfony is using the FOSUserBundle https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle

Comment: My question: how can I get users from my database. Now I can login with  user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] } but not with users stored in my database.

Comment: Also I have everything set up for it, I don't have the part in the security file however that is needed

Answer (score 0):

Your functions `serialize()` and `unserialize($serialized)` use `$this->id` instead of `$this->userid` that you used in your code before. The [Symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) explain why serialization is so important—see especially the section under "What is the importance of serialize and unserialize?"

Comment: I have edited the code but I still get 'bad credentials'